# Unable to read collection data in mongo/node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying out mongoDB in nodeJs and am having trouble with the db collection file on the mongodb server. The server is setup as a window service so it is up and running. I got nodejs to connects to it when ran. I did the mock examples and it works (I think it is properly set up).

If I want to see the collection created in nodejs it shows them. If I go to the mongodb server database(data\db folder) I see a collection has been created. The problem is when I open another instance of cmd.exe enter mongodb and want to see what is in the collection *db.collections-2* what returns is NaN.

I may be doing something wrong or there is a missing file I am not aware of. Could someone please advise me and explain why I am getting NaN.

The nodejs code is bellow.

```
var MongoClient=require('Mongodb').MongoClient,format = require('util').format;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
}
else{
    console.log("connected to", url );
} 
var user1 = {name: 'modulus admin', age: 42, roles: ['admin', 'moderator', 'user']};
var user2 = {name: 'modulus user', age: 22, roles: ['user']};
var user3 = {name: 'modulus super admin', age: 92, roles: ['super-admin',  'admin', 'moderator', 'user']};

 collection.find({name: 'modulus user', roles:  'user'}).toArray(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else if (result.length) {
    console.log('Found:', result);
  } else {
    console.log('No document(s) found with defined "find" criteria!');
  }
})

  db.close()
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are a few things in your question that are unclear, let me try to clarify :

You won't be able to read the collection data directly in data/db, you must use the mongo shell.

In the mongo shell, which I assume is what you refer to by *"open another instance of cmd.exe enter mongodb"*, try entering the following commands :

```
 use myproject 
show collections
db.mycollection.find({}) //replace 'mycollection' by the name of the collection
```

That will show you the first docs of the collection 'mycollection'.

However, in your node code, you don't seem to be defining the collection name?
It should look like this :

```
 var collection = db.collection('mycollection')
 collection.find({name: 'modulus user', roles:  'user'}).toArray(...
```

Comment: Ok Thanks I tried what you suggested but I am getting ....[thread1] ReferenceError: collection is not defined @(shell):1:1

Answer (score 0):

I have gone throw your code and have corrected a few mistakes ,
- you have to return your `console.log(error)` or otherwise the code the is not wrapped in else will get run anyway . 
- you have to actually insert data in a collection with `db.collection('name').insert(data)`
- you have to specify name of the collection `db.collection('name')`

```
var MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient
var format = require('util').format;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
    if(err){
        return console.log(err); // return your response otherise the code that isn't 
        // wrapped in else will get run anyway
  }
  else{
      console.log("connected to", url );
  } 
  var user1 = {name: 'modulus admin', age: 42, roles: ['admin', 'moderator', 'user']};
  var user2 = {name: 'modulus user', age: 22, roles: ['user']};
  var user3 = {name: 'modulus super admin', age: 92, roles: ['super-admin',  'admin', 'moderator', 'user']};

  // insert data 
  db.collection('users').insert(user1)
  db.collection('users').insert(user2)
  db.collection('users').insert(user3)

  // collect data from users table
 db.collection('users').find({name: 'modulus user', roles:  'user'}).toArray(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else if (result.length) {
    console.log('Found:', result);
  } else {
    console.log('No document(s) found with defined "find" criteria!');
  }
})

  db.close()
 })
```